# Gulp installation: 'fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported' and node-sass errors

Tags: node.js, windows, command-line, gulp

I have a new laptop and have had to reinstall gulp / npm in order to get my website files running properly locally.  However I get the following error when I run the gulp command in Windows.

> 'fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported.  If you
>   are using graceful-fs module please update it to a more recent
>   version'.

After looking into this error I have seen posts saying I simply need to run **npm  update -g npm**.  This command runs and flashes some info but then disappears before I can read the message.  I assume it is already up to date seeing as though I have just installed it! I have tried running this command both globally and within the project folder.

If I run, **npm info graceful-fs -v**, my graceful-fs version is 3.10.8

So can anyone help?  Im rubbish with this stuff :(

******UPDATE*******

I decided to uninstall **graceful-fs** and then run **npm install**.

After running gulp again I get,

> Error the 'libsass' biding was not found in...

So I then ran **npm rebuild node-sass** and get load of node-sass errors.

Please help.

[image]

Comment: What is the node version ?

Comment: Just run 'npm nodejs --version' and its 3.10.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that gulp 3.x (through vinyl-fs) uses the older version of graceful-fs. See this [link](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1640) for more info. I'm not sure but can you try updating gulp to 4.x ?

Comment: I have just installed gulp for the first time on this machine so assumed that would be the latest version?  So I need to uninstall and reinstall gulp do you think?

Comment: Ok, I have just run the following commands in the project folder and still get the same error:  npm rm -g gulp, npm install -g gulp-cli

Comment: No. It doesn't work then. Let me think of something else

Comment: OK, I have un-installed graceful-fs and then reinstalled npm.  I now get other errors to d with node-sass.  Please see edited query above :(

Comment: Can you please check running ".\node_modules\.bin\node-sass --version" to check if node-sass is installed fine. (note this command is for linux)

Comment: This thread (https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/918) suggests to delete the node_modules directory and run npm install again. Please try that too.